# Ruby regexp: complex pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a number of possible patterns for title which I want to capture using Ruby regexp.

1. Just title
2. Ignore | The title to capture
3. Ignore / The title to capture
4. [Ignore] The title to capture

How do I put this into one regexp pattern?

This method deals with the 2nd case only:

```
  def self.format_title(title)
    title.match(/(?:.+)\|(.+)/).to_a.first.strip
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be rewritten into: `title[/\|(.+)/),1].strip`

And for all four cases I recommend to use `gsub`:

```
def format_title title
    title.gsub(/.+[\|\/]/,'').gsub(/^\[.+\]/,'').strip
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^(?:[^|]*\||[^\/]*\/|\[[^\]]*\])?(.+)/
```

The optional non-capturing group `(?:[^|]*\||[^\/]*\/|\[[^\]]*\])` consists of a pattern for each case:

- **`[^|]*\|`** matches everything up to the first `|`,
- **`[^\/]*\/`** matches everything up to the first `/`, and
- **`\[[^\]]*\]`** matches everything between `[` and the first following `]` at the begin of the string

Comment: Thanks. It works fine in all the cases apart from the first one: http://www.rubular.com/r/fF6s7zkuuy

Comment: @Kernius: If your input contains line breaks but you don’t want to match then, you need to exclude them in the pattern.